# How to look-up reference code-values information in a CouchDB solution?

Tags: join, couchdb

I have some documents in CouchDB and some fields carry an abbreviation (e.g. CA, FL, NY, ...) to denote the state portion of a street address.

In some of my queries I have a need to replace the abbreviation with the expanded state name (e.g. California, Florida, New York, ...). My data actually has dozens of other abbreviated values, but the state is just an easy example.

What is the "best" (i.e. elegant, low maintenance, and relatively efficient) way to accomplish this in CouchDB?

I have found many articles on how to emulate SQL JOIN for whole documents but they focus on merging whole documents; here I'm just looking to replace single string values with a look-up result.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to create view which will replace abbreviation with full name. You can use `!json` macro to share abbreviation mapping between views.